# Enabling internal pullups when GPIO is configured as 1-wire on the Raspberry Pi 3B+

Tags: raspberry-pi, device-tree

The state of some GPIO internal pullups appears to be UP by default when not configured for anything specific (for example GPIO5). However when I enable the 1-wire interface with `dtoverlay=w1-gpio,gpiopin=5`, the internal pullup appears to be disabled.

The `/boot/overlays/README` however says:

```
Name:   w1-gpio
Info:   Configures the w1-gpio Onewire interface module.
        Use this overlay if you *don't* need a GPIO to drive an external pullup.
Load:   dtoverlay=w1-gpio,<param>=<val>
Params: gpiopin                 GPIO for I/O (default "4")
        pullup                  Now enabled by default (ignored)
```

which would suggest that the pullup is enabled by default. Any attempt to include the `pullup` parameter has not changed anything, so it seems it is ignored, but the pullup does *not* appear to be enabled.

The above just seems inconsistent to me, so I'm wondering if any experienced users have an explanation for why this is? Is it possibly a bug? Or a change in the docs required? It looks as though it is assumed the user will automatically connect an external pullup resistor when using 1-wire.

The only reliable way I have found that enables the pullup post-boot is to use `sudo raspi-gpio set 5 pu`.

Answer (score 0):

Try `params` separately and in quotes:

```
dtoverlay=w1-gpio,gpiopin="5",pullup="y"
```